# Adding SharePoint list webpart to a Specific Page after Initial deployment with CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, deployment, web-parts, csom

During the deployment of my sharepoint site, I created a few lists that I'd like to programmatically add to the home page, but I cannot find anything that works.

Right now, I'm getting the following error:

```
The property or field 'SchemaXml' has not been initialized. 
It has not been requested or the request has not been executed.
It may need to be explicitly requested.'
```

Here the code that creates the lists during the deployment:

```
ArrayList arrFields = new ArrayList();
        arrFields.Add(fieldBody);
        arrFields.Add(fieldPublishStartDate);
        arrFields.Add(fieldPublishStopDate);
        arrFields.Add(fieldReadMore);

        //create the home page content lists

        List FeaturedStories = CreateList(ctx, currentWeb, "Featured Stories", ListTemplateType.PictureLibrary, arrFields, true);
        CreateList(ctx, currentWeb, "Team Spotlight", ListTemplateType.PictureLibrary, arrFields, true);
        List quickLinks = CreateList(ctx, currentWeb, "Quick Links", ListTemplateType.Links, null, true);
        List resourceLinks = CreateList(ctx, currentWeb, "Resource Links", ListTemplateType.Links, null, true);

        arrFields.Remove(fieldBody);
        List announcementsList = CreateList(ctx, currentWeb, "News and Announcements", ListTemplateType.Announcements, arrFields, true);
        List eventsCalendarList = CreateList(ctx, currentWeb, "Events Calendar", ListTemplateType.Events, arrFields, true);

        ctx.Load(currentWeb, w => w.Lists);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Here is the code where I'm trying to add one of the lists to the home page:

```
var pageUrl = "/sites/practice3/SitePages/Home.aspx";
var xml = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("News and Announcements").SchemaXml;
var web = ctx.Web;
var lists = web.Lists;
ctx.Load(lists);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
AddWebPart(ctx, pageUrl, xml);
```

This is the method `AddWebPart`, but I have not been able to test whether this will work either since, I cannot reach the code:

```
public static void AddWebPart(ClientContext context, string pageUrl, string xml)
    {
        var page = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
        var webpartManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        context.Load(webpartManager);
        context.Load(webpartManager.WebParts);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        WebPartDefinition webpartDef = webpartManager.ImportWebPart(xml);
        WebPartDefinition webpart = webpartManager.AddWebPart(webpartDef.WebPart, "mainContent", 0);
        context.Load(webpartDef);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        //webpartManager.ImportWebPart(xml);
        //context.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading all lists information (with basic fileds) thus having an `NonInitializedProperty` exception when trying to access XML data. If you would like to get your Schema, you need to load it explicitly.

```
var pageUrl = "/sites/practice3/SitePages/Home.aspx";
// mark object you would like to access
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("News and Announcements");
// prepare load query with SchemaXml property
ctx.Load(list, l=>l.SchemaXml);
ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // request the data

AddWebPart(ctx, pageUrl, list.SchemaXml);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This fixed that issue... Thanks! Now I'm getting an error on the line in the `AddWebPart` function that says: `Cannot recognize the XML namespace of this web part`
I'm not sure why this would be, but if you have any idea that would be extremely helpful!

Comment: That's because you are passing list `SchemaXML` not the web part xml content into `webpartManager.ImportWebPart()` method. If you would like to get your web part either send the proper XML or filter `webpartManager.WebParts`  (don't forget to load that property)  to get your webpart. Then add it to the page.

Comment: I guess that's my problem because I thought the `SchemaXML` was the XML I was looking for.